# "source.fixAll.stylelint": true. for stylelint not work

Tags: stylelint

this is my code in my settings.json
this code can't Autofix fails , i don't know why?

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
```

Manually enter valid permutations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRU6.png)

settings.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywwmV.png)

package-lock.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmlh4.png)
How to make changes so that they can be automatically repaired after saving?

Answer (score 0):

[The GitHub readme of the `vscode-stylelint` extension suggests:](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint?tab=readme-ov-file#editorcodeactionsonsave)

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": "explicit"
  }
```